# mySQL SELECT MIN to multiply results

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.project_time, 
       t3.obj as start_up_obj, 
       t3.casting_meeting_date as start_up_casting, 
       t3.start_up_meeting_date as start_up_meeting_date
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 
ON t1.obj = t2.nr
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 
ON t1.obj = t3.obj
ORDER BY obj_house_floor ASC
```

With this query i build an array with lots of result.

Now i'd like to add this query to it:

```sql
SELECT start_up_meeting 
FROM table1 
WHERE obj = :obj 
ORDER BY start_up_meeting ASC LIMIT 1
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.project_time, 
       t3.obj as start_up_obj, 
       t3.casting_meeting_date as start_up_casting, 
       t3.start_up_meeting_date as start_up_meeting_date, 
       MIN(t1.start_up_meeting) as min_start_up_meeting
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 
ON t1.obj = t2.nr
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 
ON t1.obj = t3.obj
ORDER BY obj_house_floor ASC
```

This will query will only give me one result in my array.
How can i add `MIN(t1.start_up_meeting) as min_start_up_meeting` to all results?

Comment: You must obtain `MIN(..)` in subquery then join this subquery into your query. *This will query will only give me one result in my array.* The presence of aggregate function (MIN) without GROUP BY causes implicit GROUP BY where all rows are one group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.project_time, 
       t3.obj as start_up_obj, 
       t3.casting_meeting_date as start_up_casting, 
       t3.start_up_meeting_date as start_up_meeting_date,
       t4.min_start_up_meeting
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 
  ON t1.obj = t2.nr
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 
  ON t1.obj = t3.obj
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MIN(start_up_meeting) min_start_up_meeting
             FROM table1 
             WHERE obj = :obj ) t4
ORDER BY obj_house_floor ASC
```

> I cannot use = :obj Should i use On t1.obj = t4.obj ?

Of course.

```sql
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.project_time, 
       t3.obj as start_up_obj, 
       t3.casting_meeting_date as start_up_casting, 
       t3.start_up_meeting_date as start_up_meeting_date,
       t4.min_start_up_meeting
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 
  ON t1.obj = t2.nr
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 
  ON t1.obj = t3.obj
INNER JOIN ( SELECT obj, 
                    MIN(start_up_meeting) min_start_up_meeting
             FROM table1
             GROUP BY obj ) t4 
  ON t1.obj = t4.obj
ORDER BY obj_house_floor ASC
```

Comment: I cannot use = :obj Should i use On t1.obj = t4.obj ?

Comment: @BjörnC Yes. Updated.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!